# Search for different variations of text in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that consists of people and their degree type:

```
data = {'Name': ['Alice','Bob','Chris','David'],
    'Degree': ['phd','BA','MBA','B.Sc.']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Degree'])
```

And I would like to one hot encode based on the degree type:

```
data = {'Name': ['Alice','Bob','Chris','David'],
      'is_bachelors': [0,1,0,1],
      'is_masters': [0,0,1,0],
      'is_phd': [1,0,0,0]
     }
```

The problem is that people have input their degree type in lots of different ways. For example, for phd you could have PhD, phd, Ph. D, Ph.D., ph.d etc. Essentially lots of variations of spacings and periods.

Furthermore, I don't want MBA for example being flagged as bachelors (because it contains BA). I found this happened with pandas str.contains.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe try `pandas.Series.str.match` for regex matching, it gives you flexibility

Comment: This is a typical Natural Language Processing (NLP) task, and depending on how good the detection shall be it can get rather complex. One example, imagine in a text is something written about th pH value of water. What now? So you either have to create a list of "allowed terms" combined with regex and hope for the best or you have to get deep into the rabbit hole of nlp, for example with the spaCy library which can detect things like that, depending on the kind of word before them and after them.

Answer (score 1):

Since the same degree types all start with the same character you can lower them and map on the first character:

```
data = {'Name': ['Alice','Bob','Chris','David'],
    'Degree': ['phd','BA','MBA','B.Sc.']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Degree'])
df['Degree'] = df['Degree'].str.lower().str[:1].map({'b': 'is_bachelors', 'm': 'is_masters', 'p': 'is_phd'})
df.pivot_table(index='Name', columns='Degree', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
```

result:

| Name | is_bachelors | is_masters | is_phd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Bob | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Chris | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| David | 1 | 0 | 0 |

NB: you can add any other relevant letters to the mapping dictionary, eg. for `dr.` add `'d': 'is_phd'`

Answer (score 0):

For the 'PhD' example that you provide, you could remove punctuation and make everything lowercase, to capture all PhDs:

```
def preprocess (degree):
    return degree.replace('.', "").lower()

data['Degree'] = data.Degree.apply(preprocess)
```

Probably, this works for most variations in other degrees as well, but I cannot assess that without knowing the other variations.

Comment: Why a function? `data.Degree.str.replace('.', "").str.lower()` would do.

Comment: I think this paired with @DaSong idea of `pandas.Series.str.match` seems to be a good idea because I unfortunately have a few degree types that don't always start with b for bachelors or p for phd (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Academic_degrees)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
import re

string= 'MBA'

if re.search('p', string, re.IGNORECASE):
    print(0)
elif re.search('m', string, re.IGNORECASE):
    print(1)
elif re.search('ba', string, re.IGNORECASE):
    print(2)
elif re.search('bs', string, re.IGNORECASE):
    print(2)
```

It solves the case sensitive, spacing, and punctuation problems. Also in cases such as 'MBA' where it contains a 'M' and 'BA' since any string containing an 'M' will be caught before it the 'BA' check.